# mapStateToProps does not re-render the component after state change

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I've been working with React/React-Native for a while now, but I'm new to Redux and I cannot find the problem. I have a RESTFull API and two main modules: the service model and the price model. Once the admin user adds a new service the user can also associate a price for that service. The problema is that when I add a service (in the NewServiceScreen) my code dispatches an action to change the redux store and therefore update the service list on the NewPriceScreen for the user to associate a price with the service that was just added.

**NewPriceScreen.js**

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        newPrice: state.newPriceReducer
    }
}

// Exports the connected NewPriceScreen
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(NewPriceScreen);
```

**NewServiceScreen**

```
...
handleSubmit = async() => {
        const { descricao } = this.props.newService;
        const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');

        axios.post('/estabelecimento/servicos/',{descricao: descricao}, {
            headers: {
                "Authorization": `Token ${userToken}`
            }
        })
        .then(res => {
            Alert.alert(
                'Deu tudo certo :)',
                'Dados salvos com sucesso !',
            );
            console.log(res.data);
            this.props.dispatch({type: 'addService', newService: res.data});
        })
        .catch(error =>{
            Alert.alert(
                'Ops ! Algo aconteceu :(',
                error.message,
            );
        })
    }
...
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    newService: state.newService
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(NewServiceScreen);
```

**Reducers.js**

```
const initialState = {
    servicos: [],
    // Database variables
    servico: 0,
    duracao: '',
    custo: '',
    comissao: ''
}

export default function newPriceReducer(state = initialState, action){
    // console.log("My state")
    // console.log(state);
    switch(action.type){
        case 'setState': {
            return {
                ...state,
                servico: action.descricao,
                duracao: action.duracao,
                custo: action.custo,
                comissao: action.comissao
            }
        }
        case "ADD_SERVICES": {
            // console.log("Servicos");
            const newState = {
                ...state,
                servicos: action.servicos
            }
            // console.log(newState);
            // console.log(newState === initialState)
            return newState;
        }
        case 'addService': {
            // console.log("ADD Service");

            servicos = state.servicos;
            servicos.push(action.newService);

            const newState = {
                ...state,
                servicos: servicos
            }

            // console.log(newState);
            // console.log(newState === initialState);
            return newState
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }

}

const initialState = {
    descricao: ''
}

export default function newServiceReducer(state = initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case 'setDescricao': {
            return {
                ...state,
                descricao: action.descricao
            }
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }

}
```

**App.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from "redux";
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'

import newServiceReducer from '../reducers/NewService';
import newPriceReducer from "../reducers/NewPrice";

import logger from 'redux-logger';

const mainReducer = combineReducers({
    newService: newServiceReducer,
    newPriceReducer
})

const store = createStore(mainReducer, applyMiddleware(logger));

export default store

import React from 'react';
import { Platform, StatusBar, StyleSheet, View, AsyncStorage, ImageBackground} from 'react-native';
import { AppLoading, Asset, Font, Icon } from 'expo';
import AppNavigator from './navigation/AppNavigator';

// Redux Stuff
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import AppStore from './store/App';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        isLoadingComplete: false,
        isLoggedIn: false,
    };

    render() {
        if (!this.state.isLoadingComplete && !this.props.skipLoadingScreen) {
            return (
                <AppLoading
                    startAsync={this._loadResourcesAsync}
                    onError={this._handleLoadingError}
                    onFinish={this._handleFinishLoading}
                />
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <Provider store={AppStore}>
                    <ImageBackground source={require('./assets/images/back.png')} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
                        {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar barStyle="default" />}
                        <AppNavigator />
                    </ImageBackground>
                </Provider>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is that you're accidentally mutating your state.  Please try replacing your `createStore()` call with the [`configureStore()` function from Redux Starter Kit](https://redux-starter-kit.js.org/api/configureStore).  It checks for state mutations by default, and will throw an error if you do mutate.

Comment: @markerikson Oh, you're right. The way that I was adding a new element to the array turned out to be some kind of mutation on the store state, therefore the solution was just to change it

Answer (score 0):

In lines:

```
servicos = state.servicos;
servicos.push(action.newService);
```

I was making some sort mutation. I just changed it to:

```
const newState = {
    ...state,
    servicos: [...state.servicos, action.newService]
}
```